# Flex: configuration variable 'runtime-shared-library-path' requires a value for 'rsl-url'

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

When I am trying to export release for Android and iOS, its gives the following error.

Encountered errors or warnings while building project XXXX.mxml.
    configuration variable 'runtime-shared-library-path' requires a value for 'rsl-url'

Recently I have changed structure of application which is 
Mobile Application 
Library1 
Library2

Before I have only one library and it was working fine.

please help me..?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution... Some swc's link type are rsl that why this error occurs. Need to change it to merge into code.